# Object not added to one $scope variable but to all others

Tags: angularjs

Everytime I want to add a form to fill out a new contact person of a customer company I call this function:

```
$scope.addContact = () => {
    $scope.selectedCustomer.contacts.push({});
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.selectedCustomer));
};
```

But I noticed there is one customer that *magically* loses that contact object at somepoint after the method is called and I don't know why, because in the debugger only some standard angularjs methods are executed that shouldn't play a role in this and I don't understand them.

Usually the console looks like this:
1st, 2nd and 3rd click on *add contact* button results in:

```
{"id":135,"masterData":{},"name":"Normal Test","contacts":[{}]}
{"id":135,"masterData":{},"name":"Normal Test","contacts":[{"$$hashKey":"object:2205"},{}]}
{"id":135,"masterData":{},"name":"Normal Test","contacts":[{"$$hashKey":"object:2205"},{"$$hashKey":"object:2207"},{}]}
```

But for one object (so far, but I think there are more) the same situation prints this:

```
{"id":150,"masterData":{},"name":"Test AG","contacts":[{}]}
{"id":150,"masterData":{},"name":"Test AG","contacts":[{}]}
{"id":150,"masterData":{},"name":"Test AG","contacts":[{}]}
```

As you see there is an empty object added but not saved, every time I click *add contact* again, the contacts array is empty at first.

In the mongo db those two customers look exactly the same:
[image: Working]
[image: Not working]

What else can I analyze to find out where the problem is and what to do about it?

> EDIT
>    By debugging I found the place where the workflow traverses a different path when it's not working:
>   contentscript.js, line 1114 `var observerHandler = function(mutations) {...` is traversed when it works, but not reached during the failing process - it is called after: `return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ? jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;` in jquery.js, line 5013.
>   My HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="contacts" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ansprechpartner</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <table id="contacts" ng-if="selectedCustomer.contacts.length"
               class="table-condensed" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Telefon</th>
                <th>E-Mail</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in selectedCustomer.contacts">
                <td>
                    <a class="delete" ng-hide="readonly" ng-click="deleteContact(contact)">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
                    </a>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                           ng-readonly="readonly" ng-model="contact.name"
                           placeholder="keine Angabe">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-readonly="readonly"
                           ng-model="contact.phone" placeholder="keine Angabe"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-hide="readonly"
                           ng-model="contact.email" placeholder="keine Angabe"/>
                    <a href="mailto:{{contact.email}}" ng-show="readonly">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"
                               ng-readonly="readonly" ng-model="contact.email"
                               placeholder="keine Angabe"/>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="addContact" ng-hide="readonly">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-sm" ng-click="addContact()"
                    type="button">+ Ansprechpartner hinzufügen...
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your html? it might be a scope problem.

Comment: @UtkuApaydin Added it, just can't understand why it works on some selectedCustomers and not on other, cannot see any differences between those who and work and those who don't